# Java project unknown enum in web.xml

Tags: web.xml, servlet-filters

I am learning about filters. So I have the following code in my web.xml:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>asyncFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>el.test.AnyRequestFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>asyncFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I write is is autocompletes me `ASYNC`, but after that it becomes in red colour and IntelliJ show me that the error is that is is `unknown enum`.
Why is that? 
Thanks for your attention.

P.S. I have problems with following code too:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/view/badRequest.jsp</location>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
</error-page>
```

on `<error-code>` it is written `no child element expected at this point`, but the code is working(I can run it).

Answer (score 0):

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/819-3669/bnagf/index.html

```
4.In the Add Filter Mapping dialog, select one of the following dispatcher types:

REQUEST: Only when the request comes directly from the client
FORWARD: Only when the request has been forwarded to a component (see Transferring Control to Another Web Component)
INCLUDE: Only when the request is being processed by a component that has been included (see Including Other Resources in the Response)
ERROR: Only when the request is being processed with the error page mechanism (see Handling Servlet Errors)
```

So ASYNC is not a valid value.

Edit : it seems it was added in javaee 6 : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

So maybe you have some configuration problem of JRE/JDK version with your project and IDE.

Comment: Actually, it compiles and runs OK, but it is weird that IDE shows it as error. I try to rebuild, to restart and no effect.

Comment: I assume you compile with integrated tools like maven configured in java 1.6+ and run it too. But is your ide is running with a JDK/JRE 1.6+ ? And is it configure with the appropriate setting, ie java version, version of some facets ?

Comment: I configure JDK/JRE from settings. But another things - JavaEE version and so on, I don't touch them. Should add somewhere path to some JavaEE files (like the path to standart jdk)? I am new in JavaEE and I don't understand what really going on under the hood.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: And how can I configure EE version?

Comment: To be honest i'd have a hard time telling. Check your global configuration (workspace). Check properties of your project,  and you may have a Facets section in your projects properties, if so check there too.